# Display a string on canvas for only fraction of seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have written a code in which my word should be displayed on clicking start button for some fraction of seconds. How do i do it?

```
function start()
    {

      block.x = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) 
      {
          resetbox(boxes[i]);


      }
    if (!continueAnimating) 
    {
        continueAnimating = true;
        animate();
    }
    }
```

And i want to display this for lets say 5 seconds: var text=randomLetter(nu);

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/r18pgfav/)

Comment: You can look into [setTimeout](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FWindowTimers.setTimeout&ei=UM6sVOnkBYmXyAT-poGoAw&usg=AFQjCNHqokpvPYgOVAoiH37wnB11Pp_GxA&sig2=v2iZ0ln8mMUMEu80LuEDEw)

Comment: Create a fiddle demo

Comment: you can see the code here @Manwal http://jsfiddle.net/r18pgfav/

Answer (score 2):

I can give you simple demo for writing and clearing text in canvas in 1 second on Button Click:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/egsyfubm/)

Code:

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

function clear(){
     ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
}

function write()
{
    var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    
    ctx.font="20px Georgia";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World!",10,50);
    
    ctx.font="30px Verdana";
    // Create gradient
    var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,c.width,0);
    gradient.addColorStop("0","magenta");
    gradient.addColorStop("0.5","blue");
    gradient.addColorStop("1.0","red");
    // Fill with gradient
    ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
    ctx.fillText("Big smile!",10,90);
}

function start()
    {
        write();
        setTimeout(function(){
            clear();
        },1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Below Code** - You have to use [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

**[Click Here to See Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/9zfn9d7k/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="someDiv">Your Text Here</div>
<input id="SomeButton" type="button" value="Start">
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#someDiv").hide();
    $("#SomeButton").click(function(){            
        start();
    });        
});

function start()
{
    $("#someDiv").show();
    setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#someDiv").fadeOut(1000, function () { $(this).hide(); });
                }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: @Prog yup i used setTimeout and it helped. Thank you

Comment: `upvote` the answer will helps other to find out the correct solutions - Glad to help you